# Give an example of a sequence that tends to infinity but is not increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

I initially thought I had found one: $a_n = n(-1)^n $ but I don't think this tends to $\infty$ as I have a subsequence that tends to -$\infty$

Comment: How does that tend to infinity?

Comment: my bad, have edited

Comment: $a_n=n$ for $n\neq 2$ and $a_2=0$

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of examples. You can define $a_n=n$ when $n$ is odd and $a_n=\frac{n}{2}$ when $n$ is even, that will work.

Comment: Isn't this increasing?

Comment: No. The first elements are $1,1,3,2,5$ so it is already not increasing.

Comment: But what about the subsequence (1,3,5,...)?

Comment: @Neo What about it? You didn't say the sequence can't have any increasing subsequences.

Comment: @Neo, OP only asked for the sequence itself not to be increasing. By the way, there is no sequence of real numbers which goes to infinity and has no increasing subsequence. You can try to prove it.

Comment: Ah I see, googled the definition. Increasing = for all $a_n$, if $a_{n+1}>a_n$

Comment: wait so can someone explain to me why my sequence does not tend to infinity?

Comment: Well, you explained that yourself-it has a subsequence which tends to $-\infty$.